# Office 2010 GPO - Block macros, but still warn about them?

Tags: security, microsoft-office-2010

I'm planning on setting up a GPO to disable any unsigned macros in Office 2010 documents.  Seems easy enough:

> Disable all except digitally signed macros: The application displays the Trust Bar for digitally signed macros, allowing users to enable them or leave them disabled. Any unsigned macros are disabled, and users are not notified.

Except what I'd really like is to still show the warning that macros have been disabled, but *not* have the 'Enable Content' button.  So users still know that some features of the document might be broken, but they can't just randomly hit the enable button.

Is that possible?  Or is the only option to disable without any notifications?

Comment: Does the 'Enable Content' button have a Control ID? If so, you can disable that Control ID with Group Policy.

Comment: @joeqwerty that's an excellent idea, I'll have to look.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have known it to be, this has always been an on-off switch. If it's off, you know it's off because it doesn't do what it's supposed to do. If it's on, it tells you. Maybe along with the GPO you can send a message to them letting them know.